# How do I direct logging output to exclusively to different loggers with Log4J

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I'd like to use Log4J to send output of a very specific nature to a different log from that specified for everything else. Right now, I have a log4j.properties that looks a bit like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,catchall
log4j.logger.SPECIAL_LOGGER=INFO,specials
... catchall, specials appenders defined
```

I want ONLY the output from the Logger `SPECIAL_LOGGER` in the `specials` appender - easy enough - but I DO NOT want the output from `SPECIAL_LOGGER` in my `catchall` appender. I think this means I can't do what I need with log levels.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set an appropriate additivity. Add this line to your log4j configuration.

```
log4j.additivity.SPECIAL_LOGGER=false
```

Comment: I did not know about that feature. A great answer and does exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my app to make it work.
You need to create separate appender in your log4j.xml, something like this may help :

```
<appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="logs/date.log" />     
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss z} %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] %C:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Using different params in appender, you can customize it as per your own way.

Comment: I am using appenders already, but I need to exclude from one. @adarshr's answer seems to be spot on for that.